# How to share data to my Flutter app from browser and another apps?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to share data from browser and another apps with "share" button to my Flutter app or it is only for native iOS apps?

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25991) what you need? (see the comments, contrary to popular advice ;)).

Comment: He/she is just trying to add this app into the list of the share options. I tried to update the question for making it clearer but stackoverflow prevented me to edit it because of too many suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
<intent-filter
    android:label="Share with my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add this to your android manifest file to make it happen.

In case fo IOS use the more button and you can choose the app you need to appear on the list.

[Refer](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/add-remove-reorder-share-sheet-options-your-iphone-0155436/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20or%20remove%20apps,to%20rearrange%20the%20list%27s%20order.) this link on how to make it in IOS

Comment: I believe..it's not a suitable answer.. because the question is..to share "from" browser or any other apps "to" Flutter app.. however [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share#-example-tab-) plugin is for doing the reverse task..... correct me if I'm wrong..TQ:)

Comment: Are you sure about iOS? Because I can't see most of apps on my phone on this list, so I think at least some special settings are required

Comment: I suppose this is the solution from the flutter docs, that you used in your answer about Android https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

Comment: But question about iOS is still open